# Vertical Align middle

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

how to make link "test" stay in the middle of grey box when the grey box is resized?

here is the code :
http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/LXHmz/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div.grid_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xUQnR/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not correctly in the middle.. it's under the middle line... cause links top start from the 50% of parent container top...

Comment: @Good.Dima Did you notice margin-top?

Comment: do nearly the same via tables and compare)